# Passing a Socket.IO instance to route files

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am looking to share the a socket.io instance with my express route files.

I previously had the socket.io listener in one routes file, `orders.js` on port `5200` and the express server listening in `app.js` on port `5000`, however my cloud service required me to use one port for both, so I did have moved them both to `app.js`. The code below has been drastically simplified to remove noise

**./app.js**

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const socket = require('socket.io');
const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`[!] Listening on 
port: ${chalk.green(port)}`))

const io = module.exports = socket(server);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/', router)
```

**./routes/index**

```
 const express = require('express');
 const router = express.Router();
 router.use('/orders', require('./orders'));

  module.exports = router;
```

**./routes/orders.js**

```
 const express = require('express');
 const router = express.Router();
 const io = require('../index');


 io.on('connection', (client) => {
console.log("CLIENT CONNECTED");
 })

 router.get(... etc etc
```

I expect to get a connection console but instead I'm getting an error that IO is not a function. When I `console.log(io)` I get `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const user = require('{SET FILE PATH}');

 io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('Socket connected...', socket.id);      

  socket.on('login', function (req) {
    user.login(socket, req, 'login'); // socketObj , req , methodName
  })
});
```

**user.js**

```
class User {

   login(socket, req, methodName) {
      console.log("Socket ref is ::: " , socket);
   }

}

module.exports = new User();
```